# Android Studio IDE can't find NDK header files

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I'm using OpenGL ES2 inside an android app inside C++ code.
Compiling and executing the program works as planned, however the IDE itself cannot find the NDK header files leaving my code files ugly:

[image: Code file with include errors]

My cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library(native-lib
         SHARED
         openGLRenderer.cpp
         androidInterface.cpp
            )
target_link_libraries(native-lib
                   android
                   log
                   EGL
                   GLESv2
                    )
```

build.gradle:

```
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti"
            arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21',
                    '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
        }
```

...

```
    externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe this.
The fix is to use the other slashes.
So instead of:

```
#include <GLES2\gl2.h>
```

do

```
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
```

It still compiled fine and both preview and compile worked in Visual Studio where I had it before.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the header files to your cmake file with "include_directories"?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
project(GL3Lib)
# now build app's shared lib

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wc++11-extensions -Werror -Wno-deprecated -std=c++11")

add_subdirectory(freetype)
include_directories(freetype/include)
include_directories(common)
include_directories(utils)
include_directories(rendering/text)

file(GLOB UTILS_HEADERS "utils/*.h")
file(GLOB COMMON_HEADERS "common/*.h")
file(GLOB TEXT_HEADERS "rendering/text/*.h")
file(GLOB UTILS_HEADERS "utils/*.h")

set(JNI_SRCS
    JNI_Api.cpp)
set(TEXT_SRCS
    rendering/text/Font.cpp
    )
set(UTIL_SRCS
    common/Utils.cpp
    )


add_library(gl3 SHARED
            ${JNI_SRCS}
            ${TEXT_SRCS}
            ${UTIL_SRCS}
            ${UTILS_HEADERS}
            )


# MESSAGE( STATUS "CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR:         " ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} )

# add lib dependencies
target_link_libraries(gl3
                      android
                      freetype
                      log
                      EGL
                      GLESv3
                      )
```